# Credit memo return to stock adds a quantity to configurable and simple

Tags: magento-2.1.3, creditmemo, manage-stock

When a simple product that is configured to a configurable is bought then refunded and the 'return to stock' check box is ticked, it will return to stock the simple correctly but it will also add a quantity to the configurable product e.g configurable is set to 0 and the simples have their corresponding quantity, but when the refund goes through the configurable gets a 1 in quantity.

I have read that 'return to stock' can not be used when using a payment gateway?

Should my configurable be set to 'manage stock = no'? its currently set to yes as no will not show the 'return to stock' check box therefore can't return the stock back to the simple.